# ClassCast exception Java generic types

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

first time asking around here. I'm doing an AVLTree generic and there is a method in the Node that gives me an Iterator that returns me a Object array. The thing is that when I try to get that array with the objects of one of my none generic classes it sends me this.

Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `[LestructuraDeDatos.NodoAVL;` cannt be cast to `[Lmundo.Categoria;`

Here is the node class

```
public class NodoAVL <T extends Comparable <T>>
{
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Atributos
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private NodoAVL<T> izquierdo;

private NodoAVL<T> derecho;

private T elemento;

private String criterio;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Constructor
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public NodoAVL(T elem, String crit)
{
    elemento = elem;
    izquierdo = null;
    derecho = null;
    criterio = crit;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Metodos
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public NodoAVL<T> getIzquierdo() {
    return izquierdo;
}
public void setIzquierdo(NodoAVL<T> izquierdo) {
    this.izquierdo = izquierdo;
}
public NodoAVL<T> getDerecho() {
    return derecho;
}
public void setDerecho(NodoAVL<T> derecho) {
    this.derecho = derecho;
}
public String getCriterio() {
    return criterio;
}
public void setCriterio(String criterio) {
    this.criterio = criterio;
}
public boolean soyHoja() 
{
    if(izquierdo == null && derecho == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
public T getElemento() {
    return elemento;
}
public void setElemento(T elemento) {
    this.elemento = elemento;
}

public void agregarElemento(T elemento, String Crit)
{
    //Buscarlo antes de agregar, no puede haber iguales en el arbol
    if(buscarElemento(Crit)==null)
    if(soyHoja())
    {
        if(elemento.compareTo(this.elemento)>0)
        {
            NodoAVL<T> nuevo = new NodoAVL<T>(elemento, Crit);
            setDerecho(nuevo);
        }else if(elemento.compareTo(this.elemento)<0)
        {
            NodoAVL<T> nuevo = new NodoAVL<T>(elemento, Crit);
            setIzquierdo(nuevo);
        }
    }else
    {
        NodoAVL<T> nuevo = new NodoAVL<T>(elemento,Crit);
        if(this.elemento.compareTo(elemento)>0 && izquierdo == null)
        {
            izquierdo = nuevo;
        }
        else if(this.elemento.compareTo(elemento)>0)
        {
            izquierdo.agregarElemento(elemento,Crit);
        }
        else if(this.elemento.compareTo(elemento)<0 && derecho == null)
        {
            derecho = nuevo;
        }
        else if( this.elemento.compareTo(elemento)<0)
        {
             derecho.agregarElemento(elemento, Crit);
        }
    }
    balanciarSubArbol();

}

public NodoAVL<T> rotarIzq(NodoAVL<T> rotar)
{
    NodoAVL<T> temp = rotar.derecho;
    rotar.setDerecho(temp.izquierdo);
    temp.setIzquierdo(rotar);
    return temp;
}

public NodoAVL<T> rotarDer(NodoAVL<T> rotar)
{
    NodoAVL<T> temp = rotar.izquierdo;
    rotar.setIzquierdo(temp.derecho);
    temp.setDerecho(rotar);
    return temp;
}

public int darBalance()
{
    if(soyHoja())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        int izq = (izquierdo == null)?0:izquierdo.darAltura();
        int der = (derecho == null)? 0 :derecho.darAltura();
        return (izq - der);
    }
}
public NodoAVL<T> dobleRotacionDerIzq(NodoAVL<T> nodo)
{
    nodo.setDerecho(rotarDer(nodo.getDerecho()));
    return rotarIzq(nodo);
}

public NodoAVL<T> dobleRotacionIzqDer(NodoAVL<T> nodo)
{
    nodo.setIzquierdo(rotarIzq(nodo.getIzquierdo()));
    return rotarDer(nodo);
}

public void balanciarSubArbol()
{
    int valor = darBalance();
    if(-2==valor || valor==2)
    {
        if(valor<0 && derecho.darBalance()<0)
        {
            if(derecho.darBalance()<-2)
            {
                derecho.balanciarSubArbol();
            }else
            {
                rotarIzq(this);
            }
        }else if(valor<0 && derecho.darBalance()>0)
        {
            if(derecho.darBalance()>2)
            {
                derecho.balanciarSubArbol();
            }else
            {
                dobleRotacionDerIzq(this);
            }
        }else if(valor>0 && izquierdo.darBalance()>0)
        {
            if(izquierdo.darBalance()>2)
            {
                izquierdo.balanciarSubArbol();
            }else
            {
                rotarDer(this);
            }
        }else if(valor>0 && izquierdo.darBalance()<0)
        {
            if(izquierdo.darBalance()<-2)
            {
                izquierdo.balanciarSubArbol();
            }else
            {
                dobleRotacionIzqDer(this);
            }
        }
    }                       
}

public NodoAVL<T> eliminarElemento(T elemento)
{

    if(soyHoja() && this.elemento==elemento)
    {
        return null;
    }else if(soyHoja() && this.elemento!=elemento)
    {
        return this;
    }
    else
    {
        if(this.elemento.compareTo(elemento)==0)
        {
            if(izquierdo != null && derecho != null)
            {
                NodoAVL<T> temp =  derecho;
                izquierdo.setDerecho(temp.getIzquierdo());
                temp.setIzquierdo(izquierdo);
                return temp;
            }
            else if(izquierdo != null)
            {
                return izquierdo;
            }
            else
            {
                return derecho;
            }
        }
        else if(this.elemento.compareTo(elemento)>0)
        {
            izquierdo = izquierdo.eliminarElemento(elemento);
            return this;

        }
        else if(this.elemento.compareTo(elemento)<0)
        {
            derecho = derecho.eliminarElemento(elemento);
            return this;
        }
        balanciarSubArbol();
        return this;
    }
}

public T buscarElemento(String criterio)
{
    if(this.criterio.equalsIgnoreCase(criterio))
    {
        return this.elemento;
    }
    else
    {
        T izq = (izquierdo != null)?izquierdo.buscarElemento(criterio):null;
        T der = (derecho != null) ? derecho.buscarElemento(criterio):null;

        if(izq != null)
        {
            return izq;
        }else if(der != null)
        {
            return der;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public IteradorAVL<T> darElementos()
{
    IteradorAVL<T> ite = new IteradorAVL<T> (this);
    return ite;

}

public int darPeso()
{
    if(soyHoja())
    {
        return 1;
    }else
    {
        int izq = (izquierdo == null)? 0: izquierdo.darPeso();
        int der = (derecho == null) ? 0:derecho.darPeso();

        return (izq+der+1);
    }
}

public int darAltura()
{
    if(soyHoja())
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int izq = ( izquierdo == null ) ? 0 : izquierdo.darAltura( );
        int der = ( derecho == null ) ? 0 : derecho.darAltura( );
        return(izq>der || izq == der)?izq+1:der+1;
    }
}
}
```

and the iterator class

```
public class IteradorAVL<T extends Comparable <T>> implements Iterator<T>{


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Atributos
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
private NodoAVL<T> arbolitoAVL;

private Object [] elementos;

private int posActual;

private int total;

private Stack<NodoAVL> nodePath = new Stack<NodoAVL>();

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Constructor
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


public IteradorAVL ( NodoAVL <T> nodo)
{
    arbolitoAVL = nodo;
    posActual = 0;
    total = nodo.darPeso();
    elementos = new NodoAVL[total];
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Metodos
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public boolean hasNext() 
{
    return(total>posActual)?true:false; 
}

@Override
public T next() {

    T siguienteT =null;
    NodoAVL<T> respuesta = arbolitoAVL;

    //Guardo el nodo actual en la lista


    //Avancce
        while (arbolitoAVL != null) {
            nodePath.push(arbolitoAVL);
            elementos[posActual] = arbolitoAVL;
            arbolitoAVL = arbolitoAVL.getIzquierdo();
            posActual++;
        }

        if (!nodePath.isEmpty()) {
            arbolitoAVL = nodePath.pop();
            posActual++;
            elementos[posActual] = arbolitoAVL;
            siguienteT = arbolitoAVL.getElemento();

            arbolitoAVL = arbolitoAVL.getDerecho();
        }
    return siguienteT;

}


@Override
public void remove() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public Object[] darArreglo()
{
    return elementos; 
}
```

Comment: The exception at least tells you you're casting from one type of array to another, which isn't permitted.  You need to show us your code so that we could also isolate the issue; we can't divine where the problem could be just from the exception.

Comment: Sorry all ready put it in

Comment: Indicate to us the line that throws the exception so we know where to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The reason ClassCastException occurs is only one that your trying to typecast an object of one class to an object of another class which are not compatible.

Example :

```
Object i = Integer.valueOf(42);
String s = (String)i;            // ClassCastException thrown here.
```